# In Ruby, is there a difference between %w(x y z) and %w[x y z]?

Tags: ruby

In Ruby, is there a difference between `%w(x y z)` and `%w[x y z]`?

I see both in docs and examples, and both seem to work for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `()` and `[]` are called delimiters, and you can use almost any non-alphanumeric character as a delimiter:

```
%w<x y z>
%w{x y z}
%w~x y z~
%w|x y z|
```

Some have different opening and closing characters (such as your two examples and my first two examples) and the rest just use the same characters at both ends.

Comment: And of course all of that applies also to `%W`, `%q`, `%Q`, `%x` and `%r`.

Answer (score 2):

No. All such expressions in ruby support (), [], {}, <>, and any 2 non-word symbols. E.g., these are all valid:

```
%w/1 2 3/
%w\1 2 3\
%w!1 2 3!
%w.1 2 3.
```